# Docker image fail running docker-entrypoint.sh, but only when running from Docker Hub?

Tags: docker

So here is my Dockerfile, simplified. The original file is https://github.com/gremo/docker-folder-mirror/blob/master/Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run my image locally (assuming the tag is `folder-mirror:latest`) **everything works fine**:

```
docker run --rm --env-file ./.env -v "${PWD}/data:/data" -v "${PWD}/logs:/var/log" folder-mirror:latest
```

However, if I try to run the image directory (from Docker Hub):

```
docker run --rm --env-file ./.env -v "${PWD}/data:/data" -v "${PWD}/logs:/var/log" gremo1982/folder-mirror
```

... it gives me **the following error**:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH":
>   unknown.

This is my first Docker image, so I'm pretty sure... I'm missing something. In fact, if I check the remote image i get:

```
/ # ls -la /usr/local/bin/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Feb 18  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 22:52 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           890 Feb 18  2020 docker-entrypoint.sh
```

That is my entrypoint is not executable. Why? Why it's working locally then?

Comment: Are you sure that `docker-entrypoint.sh` has proper rights?

Comment: Well, actually I changed the error because was wrong. It seems it can't find the executable. Why? The executable is there (`/usr/local/bin`) but it doesn't have the `x` flag. So why it's working locally?

Comment: most probably you are using a different image. Run your container using the image ID better instead of the tag so that you can see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it is working locally, I cannot answer that. Two things you should try. One as the other commenters have suggested, do a `chmod` on the script to make it executable.

The other change, according to the Docker [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd#entrypoint), the `ENTRYPOINT` command takes two forms. The `exec` form and the `shell` form. You are using the `exec`. It is possible that your environment variables are not being loaded correctly.

Try change to `shell` form.

Comment: Solved using chmod in Dockerfile. Maybe, buling under windows, the executable is copied with the +x flag?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone run into this problem, I was having a similar issue when creating a new user:

```
RUN useradd --create-home appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser
USER appuser

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/home/appuser/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```

I dropped the new user and it started working. (I added the chmod just for good measure).

Notice I had to use the full path "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh", otherwise it wouldn't work.

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
```